# How to set png img over video background?

Tags: html, css

I want to put a png over my background video, but the png is behind it.

I tried using z-index, but then the video dissapears ( when I change the position from relative to absolute or fixed). Here is my hmtl and css code:

```
<div id="page2">
    <video autoplay loop muted id="video">
        <source src="Images/KeyboardVideo.mp4">
        <source src="Images/KeyboardVideo.webm">
    </video>

    <div id="servicelogo"><img src="images/htmlcssjs.png"></div>
</div>




/* CSS Document */

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

        body{
            font-family: arial,helvetica;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1{
            font-size: 6em;
            padding-top: 305px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        p{
            font-size: 2em;
        }


#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black; 
    z-index: 500;
}

#nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 100px;
    z-index: 500;
}

#nav li {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#video {
position: relative;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
background: transparent url(images/Nature2.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
z-index: -1
}

#servicelogo img{
    position: relative;
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#page2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;    
}

a {text-decoration: none;}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: white;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #7f8c8d;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: white;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #7f8c8d;
}


#page1  {background-image: url(images/Nature1.jpg); z-index: -1;}
#page3 {background-image: url(images/Nature2.jpg);}
#page4 {background-color: #2ecc71;}
```

Comment: use poster attribute to video instead. eg. `<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">`

Comment: This is a nice option, but I need my image to be over the video all the time. Here is my web page- www.deanzuna.com ( it is under construcion), and if you go to the link " services", you will se the video. I have a plan to have a nice img over that video, that stays in its place all the time.

Comment: I solved it! :) #video { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#servicelogo img{
 position: relative;
 height: 40%;
 width: 40%;
 margin-top: 8%;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

#page2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;    
}

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this snipet:

```css
.videoitem {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
}

.videoitem-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*** opacity: 0; ***/
  background: yellow;
  transition: 250ms opacity ease-out;
  line-height: 315px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.videoitem:hover .videoitem-cover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoitem">
  <div class="videoitem-embedd"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zdkWGsnzTXk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class="videoitem-cover">Hovering</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I want the png to be over the background video all the time and not only when I hover over it.

Comment: Visit my webpage ( it is still under contruction)- www.deanzuna.com and click on SERVICES. It will bring you to the background video. I plan to put an img that is centered, and stays over the video all the time.

Comment: In my example, at the css rule regarding `.videoitem-cover` you have to cut the rule `opacity: 0` and the layer stay always on the video...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I used the following CSS code:

```css
#video { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#servicelogo img{
 position: relative;
 height: 40%;
 width: 40%;
 margin-top: 8%;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

#page2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;    
}
```